# What's the "opposite" of \limits?

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

If I write something like

```
$\bigwedge^k$
```

inline, I get the desired effect -- the k is typeset up and to the right like an exponent, rather than immediately above the wedge.  If I'm in a displayed equation, though,

```
$$\bigwedge^k$$
```

typesets the k immediately above the wedge, which is not what I want.  If I had the reverse problem I could fix it using `\limits`.  How do I do the opposite?

Comment: One side remark - see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/412 regarding the usage of `$$` for displaymath.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer my own question, the opposite of `\limits` is `\nolimits`!

(I just found the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119325/definition-of-limits?rq=1), as part of an explanation on a totally different question.)

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem

```
\[\,\mathord{\bigwedge}^k\,\]
```

To understand this answer, check out page 154 (math classes) of The TeXbook by Don Knuth.

Feel free to ignore this, since `\nolimits` does not require one to manually fix spacing.

In addition: [Why is [ … ] preferable to $$ … $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: You forgot to put in the backslashes before the square brackets.