# How to put limits next to operator in align environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

In inline mathmode the limits of, say, a supremum appear next to the `\sup` operator:

```
$\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}$
```

renders to

[image]

In the align environment (and also in the equation environment) the limits appear under the operator:

```
\begin{align}
\sup_{n \in \mathbb N}
\end{align}
```

renders to

[image]

I know that I can achieve limits under the operator using `\limits`.

Is it possible to get the limits next to the operator like in the first picture while inside the align environment?

Comment: `\sup\nolimits_{n \in \mathbb N}`: the opposite of `\limits` is `\nolimits` `;-)`

Comment: Nice, thanks. If you put this in an answer I will accept it.

Comment: `\sup\nolimits{n\in\mathbb N}`. If it must the same for all operators, use the `[nonamelimits]` option of `amsmath`.

Comment: I'm almost sure this is a duplicate, so far I got https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144352/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119325/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824/35864

Comment: @moewe - Your hunch was correct... :-) (I went with the third option you identified.)